# NodeJS Proxy changes remoteAddress to 127.0.0.1

Tags: node.js

I have a round robin load balancer in from of a few servers. When I redirect the request I can see that some values from the request where changed. remoteAddress is now 127.0.0.1 and not the correct one. I tried to change the value but for some reason it doesn't work, I am not able to change it. Do you know how can I changed back to what it was (request.headers['x-forwarded-for'])? Is there any list of values that are changed when using a proxy? Thanks.

Comment: Is this server you are proxying to custom, or are you using an existing library like `express`? If you are using `express` you can just do `req.ip` if you configure it right. If it is your own code, you can use [`proxy-addr`](https://github.com/jshttp/proxy-addr). "List of values that are changed" entirely depends on your proxying. Literally anything can change.

Comment: I don't use express but I thin proxy-addr might help. I will try it and come back with a comment. Thanks.